# "Error! Object Expected" in calendar on html page

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, week-number, object-expected

I'm in the process of writing a html page with links to microsoft access to show and edit databases (a bit of context for everyone).

I want to be able to have a textbox so that when the user inputs the date, the week number of the year automatically appears so they don't have to work it out/type it in.

I found a template code that I've tweaked a little, but I just can't seem to get it working.

Each time I try to click the buttons that the code below generates, I get an error box saying there is an "object expected" but I'm not sure how to deal with that!

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Thanks for any help in advance :)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
      <form>
      yyyy-mm-dd: <input name="y" size="4" type="text" value="" class="in"> - 
      <input name="m" size="2" type="text" value="" class="in"> - 
      <input name="d" size="2" type="text" value="" class="in"> 
      <input value=" today " onclick="today(this.form)" type="button"> 
      <input value=" calculate " onclick= "day2date(this.form)" type="button"> 
      <input value=" reset " onclick="resetform1(this.form)" type="button"><br>
      <input name="err" size="50" type="text" class="flat" readonly><br>
      result:<br>
      <input name="str" size="20" type="text" class="flat" readonly><br>
      day of week: <input name="wday" size="6" type="text" readonly><br>
      iso8601 week number: <input name="wnum" size="2" type="text" readonly>
   </form>
</script>
```

Comment: where is the javascript code to populate text boxes?

Comment: Having just this code on the page creates the textboxes, it's whenever I try filling them in that I get an error message - is that what I should have?

Comment: Can you edit your question with `today` and `day2date` js function code